# Can I check the version of a package from a git repository using pkg_resources?

Tags: python, git, pkg-resources

Can I use pkg_resources to check the version of a package from a git repository?

When I use the code `pkg_resources.require("git+https://github.com/example/example@a1b2c34#egg=example")`, it fails to parse it.

Is there a better way to programmatically check the version of a package from a git repository to know whether it needs to be installed?

Comment: No. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html : "*The `pkg_resources` module distributed with `setuptools` provides an API for Python libraries to access their **resource files**…*" (Emphasize mine — *phd*).

Comment: There are a bunch of "and" and "also" after that: and APIs for managing Python’s current “working set” of active packages

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+install+programmatically